# Importing question content into Qualtrics survey (without API access)

Tags: javascript, csv, qualtrics

I am building a Qualtrics survey in which each respondent is supposed to see a subset *k* (e.g. 30) of a larger set of *n* questions (e.g. 60). These questions all have the same format but a different text, which I will have stored in a local .csv (or similar) file.

**EDIT 2:** Explicitely looking for a solution that does not require inserting all the *n* texts manually in the Qualtrics interface.

*What is the best way to import these contents into the questionnaire?*

1) One way from the Qualtrics documentation is to import a survey as a .txt file or Qualtric's .qsf format, as described here: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-tools/import-and-export-surveys/#PreparingASimpleFormatTXTFile

- The problem with building a .txt file from scratch is limited in functionality, and you cannot go back and forth between changing things in the Qualtrics editor (e.g. add more functionality) and in the .txt.
- The problem with .qsf is that it is hard to understand and manipulate, as detailed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381526/10483692

2) Qualtrics' "Loop and Merge" function allows you to loop over (and randomly select) a large number of inputs. But as far as I can see, one has to insert those contents manually.

3) I suspect that there might be another way with via embedded variables, which one might be able to set with Javascript that can be included in "Look and Feel" > "General" > "Footer". But I am not sure whether it is worth going down that road given limited knowledge of Javascript.

P.S. I am assuming the best way is to include all *n* questions in the questionnaire when building it and then randomly select *k* questions when a respondent enters the survey. Let me know if there's a way of importing *k* questions while a respondent is doing the survey.

**EDIT 1:**

As I currently do not have API access, this is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Does your Qualtrics account allow API access?  If it does, you could use the Create Question endpoint (https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#create-question) to create a new question out of each of the rows of your CSV.

Comment: Unfortunately not, and since it's the account of my institution, not sure I will get access any time soon...

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do it with one question in a loop & merge block. Generally, you would copy and paste your csv data into the loop & merge field setup and pipe the loop & merge fields into your question.

EDIT 1:
In response to updated question, there are two ways to make the n texts dynamic.

1. Use a web service to populate embedded variables from an external
   source (e.g., a database), then pipe the embedded variables into the
   loop & merge setup.
2. Populate the n texts as embedded data fields in a contact list, then
   pipe the embedded variables into the loop & merge setup (would
   require use of email invites, personal links, or authenticator). n
   texts would be defined on a per respondent basis.

Approach (1) is more likely what you would want to do. In either approach it becomes a bit trickier to process the resulting response data since you would have to cross-reference the question answers with the embedded variables.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that would require me to insert the contents stored in my local manually. I am looking for a solution that allows me to easily update my local file and then upload the contents to Qualtrics. Edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Many thanks, web service sounds promising. Can you say a little bit about how to set up such a web database, i.e. what platforms to use, for someone with little experience in database management etc.?

Comment: Use a database like MySQL which is usually included with most web hosting platforms. Seems like you would only need one table with a primary id and one or more text fields.  Then have your script (Python, PHP, etc) query the database to get the records of interest and output them as a json string.